# I created two functions: "opendoor" and "closedoor". I tried to call them in sequence but only the last one was executed

Tags: javascript, function, call, synchronous

I am an eight year old just start learning about JavaScript by myself. I learned about "function" and I created two functions. I called them "opendoor" and "closedoor". I tried to call the "opendoor" function first and then "closedoor" function. But it only shows the "closedoor" function. I couldn't understand why. Could someone help me out with this problem? thank you. Here is the code I wrote.

```
var opendoor = function() {
  var x1 = 200;
  var y1 = 117;
  var x2 = x1;
  var y2 = y1 + 250;
  var y3 = (y1 + y2) / 2;

  draw = function() {
    if (x1 < 0) {
      return;
    }
    background(242, 237, 237);
    triangle(x1, y1, x1, y2, x1 - 100, y3);
    triangle(x2, y1, x2, y2, x2 + 100, y3);
    x1 = x1 - 1;
    x2 = x2 + 1;

  };
};

var closedoor = function() {
  var x1 = 0;
  var y1 = 77;
  var x2 = 400;
  var y2 = y1 + 250;
  var y3 = (y1 + y2) / 2;

  draw = function() {
    if (x1 > 200) {
      return;
    }
    background(242, 237, 237);
    triangle(x1, y1, x1, y2, x1 - 100, y3);
    triangle(x2, y1, x2, y2, x2 + 100, y3);
    x1 = x1 + 1;
    x2 = x2 - 1;
  };
};

opendoor();
closedoor();
```

Comment: they both ran one straight after the other ... only once they both finished would you see the results in the browser (assuming this is in the browser) - of course, neither of them do anything useful

Comment: What makes you think that only the last function is called?

Comment: both functions do nothing than reassign `draw`. And since `closedoor` is the last that does reassignment the `draw` is closing the door.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the replys. I am really a beginner and have only been learning programming for less than a month. Sorry I don't know yet how to make my program useful. If this is not a place for beginners to find help, please kindly direct me to somewhere where I can ask simple questions. However, even though I still don't know how to make my two animations shown one after another, I think I understand why I only see the animation in the last function. Thank you and sorry for the stupid question.